# What is the method of finding the value of a variable in a system of equations where two or more simultaneous equations won’t intersect?

Tags: systems-of-equations

The question asks, “For what value of p will the lines 2x+3y=23 and 7x+py=8 not intersect?

I tried elimination and substitution but they both didn’t work (at least for me).

Is there any other method to work this out?

The answer provided by the textbook is p=10.5 and when I plugged it into a graphing calculator, the two lines were parallel.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How did it not work?

Comment: When do two lines not intersect?

Comment: The methods I used (substitution, and elimination)  gave me different answers

Comment: I’m pretty sure that two lines will never intersect if they have the same gradient but a different constant.

Comment: For each of them, rewrite them as $y=ax+b$

Comment: I rewrote them as 3y=-2x+23 and py=-7x+8